# Switch on 12V using 3.3V output from an ESP (switching on the +ve side of the load)

Tags: mosfet, switches, integrated-circuit

Hi I'm looking to turn on a 12V power source. Requirements are:

1. Switching on the +ve side of the load (I can't find a mofset that can do this with a 3.3V control voltage)
2. Max peak current is 2 amps maybe 3 to be safe.
3. I want the switch to be efficient and not waste power.

The control signal is 3.3V. I'd prefer 0V control = on and 3.3V off but it can be reverse if needed.

I've looked at Mosfets but this can't work switching the +ve side of the load.

What hardware should I use? Should I consider an IC switch.

OK. So this is what I ended up with. A p-type mofset and 2x NPN Transistors.
1 NPN acts as a not gate and the other switches the mofset. Thus the mofset is open when the control voltage "PWR-DIABLE" = 0 and the mofset is closed when PWR-DISABLE = 3.3V.

Did i get it right? Seems to work in the sim.

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please follow schematic best practices and use transistor symbols for transistors, not blocks. Draw positive voltages pointing up, ground and negative pointing down. Signal flow is from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a schematic grab of the most common way to do what you describe,  from this site:

https://itecnotes.com/electrical/electrical-pmos-high-side-switch/

[image]

The 5 V source can be replaced by a 12 V source.  Also, R1 can be increased to 10 K to reduce the base current.  R3 represents the load device or circuit, whatever is being powered through the switch.

When the I/O signal is low, both transistors are off and there is no 12 V current other than off-state leakage through Q1 and M1.

Q1 Can be almost any small signal NPN transistor, such as a 2N4401, 2N2222, etc.  M1 should be rated for at least 25 V and 2x the peak load current.

Answer (score 0):

At 3.3V, there's a lot of bipolar transistors and a few MOS
that work well.   I'd do this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzDaXk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At zero V out, the output should handle 100 mA or so.
Some LDO regulators, with enable inputs, might work too,
like [MCP1804 regulator](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20002200D.pdf)

Comment: :-)  I was going to add a comment on Tim's answer that noted you could drive the emitter and connect base to 3V3 to achieve the inverted logic that he wants - but you beat me to it. This topology makes some people's head explode :-).